# Django with Postgres - ProgrammingError, migrations not updating the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Recently, I changed a model called `'Objects'` by adding a `'description'` field (which has null set to True). Ever since I migrated to the Postgres database hooked up to the Django project, I have received the following error whilst trying to access the `'Objects'` model.

```
ProgrammingError at /objects/results/
column objects_objects.description does not exist
LINE 1: ...1, "objects_objects"."mapped_product_id" AS Col2, "objects_o...
```

Objects model...

```
class Objects(models.Model):
    mapped_product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='p_objects',verbose_name='Product',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True,blank=True)
    slug_key=models.SlugField(unique=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Active',default=False)
```

In the console, Django says migrations are all successful, and when running the local server it does not show that there are unapplied migrations.

Any ideas on how to sync the database up with the models from scratch? I do not mind clearing my development database for this, and have already tried removing all of the previous migrations.

I understand that this is somewhat vague at this point since I'm unsure what code I should post here - let me know if there is some code I should post here.

Comment: Did the migration file generated correctly when you typed python manage.py makemigrations?

Also, another minor thing is that model names should be singular, so in your case it should be Object

Comment: try `python manage.py migrate app_name zero` then `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Thanks for the suggestion but that did not seem to work. It even says 'description' in the migrations file however it still gives the column does not exist error when visiting a template.